# Flood fill function not producing good results

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, flood-fill

[image][image]I applied the floodfill function in opencv to extract the foreground from the background but some of the objects in the image were not recognized by the algorithm so I would like to know how I can improve my detections and what modifications are necessary.

```
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
image = cv2.resize(image, (800, 800))
h,w,chn = image.shape
ratio = image.shape[0] / 800.0
orig = image.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 200)
# show the original image and the edge detected image
print("STEP 1: Edge Detection")
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.imshow("Edged", edged)

warped1 = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
T = threshold_local(warped1, 11, offset = 10, method = "gaussian")
warped1 = (warped1 > T).astype("uint8") * 255
print("STEP 3: Apply perspective transform")

seed = (10, 10)

foreground, birdEye = floodFillCustom(image, seed)
cv2.circle(birdEye, seed, 50, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.imshow("originalImg", birdEye)

cv2.circle(birdEye, seed, 100, (0, 255, 0), -1)

cv2.imshow("foreground", foreground)
cv2.imshow("birdEye", birdEye)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(foreground, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("gray", gray)
cv2.imwrite("gray.jpg", gray)

threshImg = cv2.threshold(gray, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
h_threshold,w_threshold = threshImg.shape
area = h_threshold*w_threshold

cv2.imshow("threshImg", threshImg)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

The floodFillCustom function is as follows -

```
def floodFillCustom(originalImage, seed):

    originalImage = np.maximum(originalImage, 10)
    foreground = originalImage.copy()

    cv2.floodFill(foreground, None, seed, (0, 0, 0),
                  loDiff=(10, 10, 10), upDiff=(10, 10, 10))

    return [foreground, originalImage]
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/69UUh.jpg]

Comment: Could you add you *original* input image?

Comment: yes sure I added it!

Comment: Are you trying to create a mask of the tools? There could be a more direct approach to segment the foreground objects without using flood-fill. What are you trying to do? To answer your question: the flood-fill algorithm has a "tolerance" value that determines if the variance of the color used to create contiguous "patches" of pixels must be ignored. The "tolerance" is what makes possible to fill regions where the target color varies a little bit. In your case, the screwdriver could be above that certain tolerate, preventing the filling of the pixels. Maybe increasing the threshold can help.

Comment: yes I m trying to create a mask of the tools! Could you help me with some methods!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little bit late, but here's an alternative solution for segmenting the tools. It involves converting the image to the [CMYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) color space and extracting the `K` (Key) component. This component can be `thresholded` to get a nice binary mask of the tools, the procedure is very straightforward:

1. Convert the image to the **CMYK** color space
2. Extract the **K** (Key) component
3. **Threshold** the image via Otsu's thresholding
4. Apply some **morphology** (a closing) to clean up the mask
5. (Optional) Get **bounding rectangles** of all the tools

Let's see the code:

```
# Imports
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
imagePath = "C://opencvImages//"
inputImage = cv2.imread(imagePath+"DAxhk.jpg")

# Create deep copy for results:
inputImageCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Convert to float and divide by 255:
imgFloat = inputImage.astype(np.float) / 255.

# Calculate channel K:
kChannel = 1 - np.max(imgFloat, axis=2)

# Convert back to uint 8:
kChannel = (255*kChannel).astype(np.uint8)
```

The first step is to convert the `BGR` image to `CMYK`. There's no direct conversion in OpenCV for this, so I applied directly the [conversion formula](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-cmyk.html). We can get every color space component from that formula, but we are only interested on the `K` channel. The conversion is easy, but we need to be careful with the data types. We need to operate on `float` arrays. After getting the `K` channel, we convert back the image to an `unsigned 8-bit` array, this is the resulting image:

[image]

Let's threshold this image using **Otsu's thresholding** method:

```
# Threshold via Otsu:
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(kChannel, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

This yields the following binary image:

[image]

Looks very nice! Additionally, we can clean it up a little bit (joining the little gaps) using a `morphological closing`. Let's apply a `rectangular structuring element` of size `5 x 5` and use `2` iterations:

```
# Use a little bit of morphology to clean the mask:
# Set kernel (structuring element) size:
kernelSize = 5
# Set morph operation iterations:
opIterations = 2
# Get the structuring element:
morphKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernelSize, kernelSize))
# Perform closing:
binaryImage = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, morphKernel, None, None, opIterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)
```

Which results in this:

[image]

Very cool. What follows is optional. We can get the `bounding rectangles` for every tool by looking for the outer (external) contours:

```
# Find the contours on the binary image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binaryImage, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Look for the outer bounding boxes (no children):
for _, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Get the contours bounding rectangle:
    boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # Get the dimensions of the bounding rectangle:
    rectX = boundRect[0]
    rectY = boundRect[1]
    rectWidth = boundRect[2]
    rectHeight = boundRect[3]

    # Set bounding rectangle:
    color = (0, 0, 255)
    cv2.rectangle( inputImageCopy, (int(rectX), int(rectY)),
                   (int(rectX + rectWidth), int(rectY + rectHeight)), color, 5 )

    cv2.imshow("Bounding Rectangles", inputImageCopy)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Which produces the final image:

[image]

Comment: Awesome man!! This is just what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: @SubhamTiwari If the answer helped you, please accept it.

Comment: For some of the other images the detections are not up to the mark, do I need to change some parameter values to get bet results? Or are there any other approaches to that?

Comment: @SubhamTiwari Hard to tell without the images. Computer Vision algorithms are highly dependent of their input, if new images are too different from the original image, a new approach may be needed. The background, for example, is pretty simple in the attached image, and naturally produces a nice contrast between the foreground objects, which eases detection. If  you are testing images with complex (textured, multi-colored) background, the original approach won't be enough. If you have too many different images, acquired under different conditions, a Machine Learning approach may be needed.

Comment: Do you have any machine learning models in mind for such scenarios to get started with? I will link an Image so that you get a fair understanding of the different types of images I am dealing with!